# How to link two content types from each other

Tags: nodes

I have content type A and content type B. Users need to be able to link between them while creating either content type (A or B). When they link them up I would like it to be saved in one table. Currently using something like node reference would put it in two different tables.  Know of any module or functionality that can do that?

Clarifying 
I want a user to be able to go into content A and save a reference to content B. We also need a user to go into content B and save a reference to content A. Ideally both references would be stored in one table as a many to many relationship.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "linking between content types". Clarify? Perhaps the "entity reference" field type could serve your purpose?

Comment: Two content types saved in one table ? r u sure?

Comment: I want a user to be able to go into content A and save a reference to content B. We also need a user to go into content B and save a reference to content A. Ideally both references would be stored in one table as a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to a single table by creating one entity reference field and invoking it on both content types.

Comment: They will need to be able to search by content type name in both content types.